# Capacitor how to remove platform

Tags: capacitor

[Documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/capacitor-add) on capacitor doesn't mention how to remove a platform.

And remove does not exist.

[image]

Does capacitor even support removing of a platform? How do I remove my platform without the obvious - manually deleting the folder

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Unlike Cordova, native projects in [Capacitor](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/v3/cordova#native-project-management) are a source asset instead of a build time asset.

You will have to delete the whole project manually and re add it with `npx cap add`.

Comment: This is pretty dumb. Oh well.

Comment: Since I can't physically delete the folder because I'm doing automation on a Kubernetes server, following up on @johnborgens's answer I had to update my deployment scripts to delete the folders.

 rm -rf apps/myionicproject/android && rm -rf apps/myionicproject/ios

Comment: @nicholaslabrecque when syncing you can choose which platform to sync: `npx cap sync platform android`